# Allow typeof to accept subclasses

Tags: typescript

Consider the following four classes:

```
export class Car {

}

export class Mercedes extends Car {

}

export class Animal<T extends Car> {
    car: T;
}

export class Dog extends Animal<Mercedes> {

}
```

And another class where a reference to either of these classes is saved:

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(animalClass: typeof Animal) {}
}
```

Now, the following doesn't work:

```
let x = new MyClass(Dog);
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"* - errors? At compile time? Run time? It doesn't give any errors in the playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/); which version of TS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it turned out that the error came from a few classes deeper. Please see the updated question. I also tested the code in the playground and the error does show up now.

Answer (score 1):

For that to work, you would need to define `MyClass` as follows:

```
export class MyClass<T extends Car> {
    constructor(animalClass: new() => Animal<T>) {}
}
```

Here `MyClass` is generic type, whose constructor takes something that can construct an `Animal` of that generic type.

This is covered in the docs under [Using Class Types in Generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics).